# ->bind_global() hides view in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana

I would like to pass some data from my `Controller_Template` to my `template.php`.

Here's my controller:

```
class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'template';

    public function action_index() {

        $user = "Alice";

        $view = View::factory('user/user')
            ->bind('user', $user);

        $this->template->content = $view;
    }
}
```

Doing this means I can access `$user` in `user/user.php`, and whatever markup I have in `user/user.php` is available in `$content`.

However, I want to access `$user` in `template.php`. If I change the `bind()` method to `bind_global('user', $user)` then I can  indeed access `$user` in `template.php`.

The problem though, is that if I do that, there seems to be nothing in `$content`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$view` (or the `$content` template variable) ends up being empty when you use `bind_global()` method for one good reason — it is a static method which doesn't return anything, and since it's the last method called in the `$view` definition the `$view` variable ends up being equal `NULL`.

It is a bit unfortunate (if you ask me) that PHP allows using static methods in an object context, while at the same time it doesn't allow that with properties. And it is this inconsistency (among many others) that causes your problem here.

The way to achieve what you're after would be to bind the `$user` variable globally in via calling the `bind_global()` method statically. Full working example:

```
class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'template';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $user = "Alice";
        View::bind_global('user', $user);

        $view = View::factory('user/user');
        $this->template->content = $view;
    }
}
```

And this should work for you like a charm.